# undefined reference to SIGN in C using GCC

Tags: c, makefile

Many questions have been asked here about functions from math.h not being found in C code during compilation and I am facing a similar problem. Having gone through all of them, none seems to apply to my problem. I have some C code in a file called test1.c -

```
#include <math.h>
int main(void) {
  int j = SQR(4);
  int i = (int)(sqrt(16.0));
}
```

Now, I compile this using -

```
gcc -c -o ../../obj/test1.o test1.c -I../../include
```

And it produces the .o file.

Now, I try and create the executable using -

```
gcc -o ../../bin/test1../../obj/test1.o -I../../include -lm
```

But this gives me the error below (most previous questions were solved by the -lm switch but I have that) -

```
../../obj/test1.o:test1.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `SQR'
../../obj/test1.o:test1.c:(.text+0x13): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `SQR'
```

Strangely, sqrt works but a host of other functions like SQR, SIGN etc lead to problems (the case doesn't matter). Note that these commands were generated by a make file -

```
IDIR =../../include
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

ODIR=../../obj
LDIR =../../lib

LIBS=-lm

_DEPS = nrutil.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ = test1.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
  $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

../../bin/svdcmp: $(OBJ)
  gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
   rm -f $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

I'm using Cygwin with Windows.

Comment: There is no `SQR` function in the standard C math library.  In fact, you found the correct name, `sqrt`.  Did you think the same function was exported under multiple names?  Or that there was some subtle difference between the two?  There is also no `SIGN` function.  Instead of trying to guess library function names, you should consult the documentation and only use documented function names.

Comment: @Tom - these functions were included in the svdcmp.c code from numerical recipies with C - http://cacs.usc.edu/education/phys516/src/TB/svdcmp.c. The only includes are math.h and nrutil.h. I didn't find SIGN for example in nrutil.h so I assumed it must be in math.h.

Comment: My bad - I see these are defined in the link I provided. In the book however, these are not defined with the code.

Comment: Yes, usually in C when an uppercase name is used for something that looks like a function, it's probably a macro.

Comment: Asking in the title about `SIGN` then using `SQR` in the example is perhaps a little confusing.  Note that all standard library functions (and function-like macros) are all lower-case.  For `SIGN` you probably intended [`signbit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/signbit/). `SQR` is trivially implemented, or you might consider it a special case of [`pow()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SQR` is not a standard function, and is not declared in `math.h` or defined in the standard library.

Add your own implementation.

```
#include <math.h>

// Use a macro to define SQR
#define SQR(x) ((x)*(x))

int main(void) {
  int j = SQR(4);
  int i = (int)(sqrt(16.0));
}
```

You can also use a function

```
int SQR(int x)
{
   return x*x;
}
```

Using a function has the advantage that it does not evaluate the argument twice. The downside is that you cannot use it to compute the square of a `float` or a `double` with it.

Comment: What is the problem with a function? Aldditionally that macro evaluates `x` twice.

Comment: @Olaf, that is the downside of using a macro. The upside is that it is polymorphic.

Comment: If you need polymorphism you should use an OOP language. I prefer predictable behaviour under all circumstances. This becomes vital if you encapsulate such "helpers" in a header file. Not sure why a square function/macro is required anyway. The operation is very clear (I think this is the reason there is none in the standard library).

Comment: @Olaf, while it may not be necessary, I often use it. The abstraction -- sqaure -- is valuable. The fact that it can be implemented using a simple multiplication is a detail.